# User object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-jwt

I am currently using flask-jwt library https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt and flask-sqlalchemy.  When I pass my auth token in the header I get an error saying `User object is not callable`.  I have followed the example given here https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/ switching out the models in exchange for sqlalchemy models.  The example code returns the User object however when I switch to sqlalchemy it complains.

Here is my model:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#we should prepare the data that we need from here
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    Password = db.Column(db.String(64))
    Hosts = db.relationship('Host', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.Username = username
        self.Password = password

    def __str__(self):
        return "User(id='%s')" % self.id
```

and it fails here:

```
def identity(payload):
    print str(payload)
    print str(User.query.get(payload['identity']))
    return User.query.get(payload['identity'])
```

I can see both the payload and user being printed and this is the output:

```
{u'iat': 1464650823, u'exp': 1464651123, u'nbf': 1464650823, u'identity': 1}
User(id='1')
```

Comment: The example returns a string. You are returning a `User`. It's not a valid response-like type.

Comment: @dirn how should I go about returning the user object?

Comment: It depends on what you need to know about the user. If it's just one field, you can return a string. If you need more fields, you'll probably want to use `jsonify` to return a dictionary of the fields.